# What exactly is InstanceNormalization and BatchNormalization?

Tags: conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I know this is a question that has been asked a lot. I know there are many good explanations on this topic and videos. However, I still have a hard time to understand the relationship visually between the normalization methods and convolutional neural network.

So I looked at some articles and they all explained it with the figure below:

[image: Normalization types]

In general, I understand that Batch Norm is a normalization that is done over batches. I understand that it helps the learning and that you calculate the mean and standard deviation for each batch.

However. When I try to refer this to a convolutional neural network (below) I don't really understand what exactly the H, W, C and N is. What I think they describe is the following:

N describes the number of batches and in the figure, this number is 6. This means that everytime I am training one run I use 8 images per batch. C describes the channels and they refer to the number of feature maps. H, W I don't understand.

[image: Convolutional Neural Network]

What I am seeking is a 1:1 relationship of what (H, W), C and N is versus for Convolutional Neural Networks. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are two dimensional; H and W are the height and width of the image. N is the batch size. C is the number of channels (e.g. CNN filters).

Comment: So is C the number of feature maps? E.g. number of kernels applied? and is N the number of batches?